# How can i make Mac Java_Home tool to work?

Tags: java, macos

How can i make  java_home tool(i.e /usr/libexec/java_home)  to work on my mac?I am a mac newbie.Mac Java-home tool says unable to find JVM installed but JVM is installed on my machine and the  java -version return true as shown below

````
    $ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
Matching Java Virtual Machines (0):

Default Java Virtual Machines (0):

No Java runtime present, try --request to install

```$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.29+3-CA (build 11.0.2+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.29+3-CA (build 11.0.2+7-LTS, mixed mode)
````

Answer (score 0):

Open up Terminal.app (Applications >> Utilities >> Terminal)

Type: `nano .profile`

add this to the end of the `.profile` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export JAVA_HOME;
```

Save and exit (ctrl-x and y to confirm)

--- edit

Only now I saw, you are using open jdk, try it:

Before setting the path make sure that java is installed by checking the directory

terminal > type `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

You will see java versions installed

Then in .bash_profile

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<version>.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME
```

terminal type `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload

Comment: i  have already added  java home in .bash_profile  and i still have the same issue.Do i need to add in .profile  file  again?

Comment: Does  the  java_home tool  look  for  <version>.jdk pattern?I  have the  JDK  folder .Let me  try that  pattern